# how to reset password in SAP system using BAPI?

Tags: java, change-password, sap-basis, bapi, jco

I am trying to reset password for SAP system using BAPI but I am getting error

> password is not type of field input

I am posting my code below.

`getRandomString()` is a user-defined function.  I have copied this code from Internet and I am unaware about this.

`String newPassword = getRandomString();` here it is giving error because `getRandomString()` is a user-defined function and I am unaware about this.

Is there any role of this while resetting password or can I directly use `String newpassword=" ";`?

```
String newPassword = getRandomString();

try{
      JCO.Function bapiUserChange = repository.getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_USER_CHANGE").getFunction();
      if(bapiUserChange != null){
           JCO.ParameterList userChangeInput = bapiUserChange.getImportParameterList();
           
           JCO.Structure sPassword = userChangeInput.getStructure("PASSWORD");
           
           //sPassword.setValue(newPassword, ????) //what do I assign it to?
           
           userChangeInput.setValue(userId, "USERNAME");
           userChangeInput.setValue(newPassword, "PASSWORD");  // this gives an error
           userChangeInput.setValue("X","PASSWORDX"); //I know "X" is true, this will give an error too I believe
           
           mConnection.execute(bapiUserChange);
           
           //send E-mail
           boolean emailSent = sendEmail(userId, newPassword, "XXX200");
           msgMgr.reportSuccess("Password Reset Done");     
           
           if(mConnection != null){
                mConnection.disconnect();
           }
                     
      }
}catch(Exception e){
     msgMgr.reportException("Could not change password " + e.getMessage(),true);
}
```

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to reset password in SAP using BAPI\_USER\_CHANGE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532803/how-to-reset-password-in-sap-using-bapi-user-change)

Comment: You have asked the same question twice.  Please, delete the other question.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `PASSWORD` is typed as `BAPIPWD` which is a structure what in turn contains only a single field named `BAPIPWD`. Therefore, you need to access the structure approximately like this:

```
JCO.Structure sPassword = userChangeInput.getStructure("PASSWORD");
sPassword.setValue(newPassword, "BAPIPWD");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using BAPIPWD or PASSWORD-BAPIPWD instead of PASSWORD, and just in case make sure the password is all caps